# Add a comma at every nth position from the right of every line in C

Tags: c

I have a file like this:

`cat file.txt`

```
100000000
1000000
10000000
```

I would like to generate:
`cat result.txt`

```
100,000,000
1,000,000
10,000,000
```

So far I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    FILE *file_to_read = fopen("file.txt","r");
    FILE *file_to_write = fopen("result.txt","w");
        char str[60];
    while(fgetc(file_to_read) != EOF){
        if( fgets(str, 60, file_to_read) != NULL ){
            fputs(str,file_to_write);
        }
    }
    fclose(file_to_read);
    fclose(file_to_write);
    return (0);
}
```

Should I use strtok to add the commas from the right side at every third position?

Comment: No, `strtok()` is not the function you are looking for.

Comment: Your call to `fgetc` in the loop condition will read the first character of each line, and then just drop it. You will loose the first character of each line. Why don't you call `fgets` in the loop condition?

Comment: You may want to just use a `%'d` printf format specifier.

Comment: Also, `"100"` becomes `",100"`? `"fubar"` becomes `"fu,bar"`?

Comment: @pmg Im not adding to the beginning of the lines. Only in the middle of the strings

Comment: OT: you need to check if `fopen` succeeds

Comment: Does code need to handle numbers that begin with `'-'` or `'+'`?  What is the largest number to handle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple implementation assuming input lines contain only digits (error checking and input validation omitted for brevity):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char line[1000];
    FILE *ifp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    FILE *ofp = fopen("result.txt", "w");

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, ifp) != NULL) {
        const int len = strchr(line, '\n') - line;
        fprintf(ofp, "%.*s", (len - 1) % 3 + 1, line);
        for (int i = (len - 1) % 3 + 1; i < len; i += 3)
            fprintf(ofp, ",%.3s", &line[i]);
        fputc('\n', ofp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my attempt at a `commaize()` function. This function "commaizes" every string, whether they represent a number, whether they already have commas in them, .... For example: `"-100"` commaizes to `"-,100"`

```
#include <string.h>

void commaize(char *restrict dst, const char *restrict src) {
    unsigned srclen = strlen(src);
    if (srclen < 4) {
        while ((*dst++ = *src++)) /* void */;
        // dst is properly terminated
    } else {
        switch (srclen % 3) {
            case 0: *dst++ = *src++; // fallthrough; copies 3 chars
            case 2: *dst++ = *src++; // fallthrough; copies 2 chars
            case 1: default: *dst++ = *src++; break; // copy 1 char
        }
        do {
            *dst++ = ',';                                      // commaizes
            *dst++ = *src++; *dst++ = *src++; *dst++ = *src++; // copies 3 chars
        } while (*src);
        *dst = 0; // properly terminate dst
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

strtok() is used in order to split a string based on a selected delimeter (e.g. the '-'). This is not the case here.

First of all you would have to allocate the required space for each line which would be:

```
len = sizeof(line)
new_line_size = len + len/3 +  (len % 3 == 0) ? 0 : 1
```

Then you will have to put the first comma in the position:

```
len % 3 if (len % 3 != 0)
```

and then put a comma every 3 digits.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which reads one character at a time and uses the standard input/output streams.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN(array) (sizeof (array) / sizeof (array)[0])

int main(void)
{
    int n, i, j, ch;
    char buf[256];

    n = 1;
    i = 0;
    ch = getchar();
    while (ch != EOF) {
        if ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9')) {
            /*copy character to buffer*/
            if (i < LEN(buf)) {
                buf[i] = ch;
                i++;
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Integer number %d has too many digits, maximum is %d\n", n, LEN(buf));
                exit(1);
            }
        } else if (i > 0) {
            /*print number*/
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if ((j > 0) && ((i - j) % 3 == 0)) {
                    putchar(',');
                }
                putchar(buf[j]);
            }
            putchar('\n');
            n++;
            i = 0;
        }
        ch = getchar();
    }
    return 0;
}
```